# Values doesn't override in magento using soap api from external php site duplicacy issue

Tags: magento-1.9, php

[image]

this is my code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "mypasswrd";
$dbname = "dbname";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$client = new SoapClient('myurl');
$session = $client->login('usr', 'pswrd');
// get attribute set
$attributeSets = $client->call($session, 'product_attribute_set.list');
$attributeSet = current($attributeSets);
$query="select * from stock";
 $resultt=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        if($resultt->num_rows > 0)
          {

         while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultt))
          {
       $name=$row['stock_name'];   
     $result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.create', array('simple', $attributeSet['set_id'], rand(), array(
    'categories' => array(2),
    'websites' => array(1),
    'name' => $name,
    'description' => 'Nyc one',
    'short_description' => 'nyc tt',
    'weight' => '10',
    'status' => '1',
    'url_key' => 'product-url-key',
    'url_path' => 'product-url-path',
    'visibility' => '4',
    'price' => '1000',
    'tax_class_id' => 1,
    'meta_title' => 'Product meta title',
    'meta_keyword' => 'Product meta keyword',
    'meta_description' => 'Product meta description'
)));
          }
          }
          else
          {
         echo "fail";

          }
var_dump ($result);
$conn->close();
?>
```

how to match the product name of my external table with product name of a magento table?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <?php
    include("config_stock.php");// loacal data
    include("config_magento.php");//magento dta base configuration
    $client = new SoapClient('url');
    $session = $client->login(username, pasword);
    $attributeSets = $client->call($session, 'product_attribute_set.list');
    $attributeSet = current($attributeSets);
    $sql="select * from stock";
    $res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if($res->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
            $sku=$row['sku'];
            $stock_name=$row['stock_name'];
            $sql1="select * from mgrm_catalog_product_entity where sku='$sku'";
            $res1=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
            if($res1->num_rows > 0)
            {
                echo "Exist";
            }
            else
            {
                $result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.create', array('simple', $attributeSet['set_id'], $sku, array(
                    'categories' => array(2),
                    'websites' => array(1),
                    'name' => $stock_name,
                    'description' => 'Nyc one',
                    'short_description' => 'nyc tt',
                    'weight' => '10',
                    'status' => '1',
                    'url_key' => 'product-url-key',
                    'url_path' => 'product-url-path',
                    'visibility' => '4',
                    'price' => '1000',
                    'tax_class_id' => 1,
                    'meta_title' => 'Product meta title',
                    'meta_keyword' => 'Product meta keyword',
                    'meta_description' => 'Product meta description'
                )));
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```